# am I using the wrong type of random.RandomGen?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use normals' from the Data.Random.Normal, and it should accept a Random.RandomGen (from System.Random).

```
r <- newStdGen
normals' (mean, sigma) r
r:: StdGen
```

StdGen is an instance of random.RandomGen, and I thought it should work. Could someone please understand what I am doing wrong?

I tested the working example suggested below, and get this error message:

```
No instance for (random-1.0.1.1:System.Random.RandomGen StdGen)
  arising from a use of ‘normals'’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘normals' (50, 1) myRandomGen’
In the expression:
    take 10 $ normals' (50, 1) myRandomGen :: [Double]
In an equation for ‘samples’:
    samples = take 10 $ normals' (50, 1) myRandomGen :: [Double]
```

I tried to check if there where some packages not installed, but random-1.1 and normaldistribution is installed. I did not realise that I had two user packages of random (suggested by Thomas) so removing one of them made it work (cabal-uninstall random --force). I also think that me not giving type (suggested in the accepted answer) would also be a problem.

Comment: Please show the error you are getting. Your program looks perfectly reasonable to me (except the trailing `r :: StdGen`, unless you are showing input to GHCi).

Comment: Definitely show error and more context; your example doesn't give an error for me in GHCi. (Although it does give an infinite list that I have to interrupt.)

Comment: Notice the explicit version in the error suggests you have two versions of `random` installed, which causes problems.

Comment: @Thomas. thank you - i did not think about that possibility, but I thought cabal cleaned up older versions.

Comment: @Thomas. That worked (uninstalling one of my random packages..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example works for me:

```
import System.Random
import Data.Random.Normal

main = do
  myRandomGen <- getStdGen
  let -- myRandomGen = mkStdGen 3
      samples    = take 10 $ normals' (50, 1) myRandomGen  :: [Double]
  print samples
```

Note I needed to give a type for `samples`.